# Cant run/find Executable Swift Package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Bottom line I am trying to run an executable from a swift package I created and linked to my target.

I think I'm missing something here, so I've created an executable swift package with the content

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "AutoLocalized",
platforms: [
    .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v12)
],
products: [
    .executable(name: "autolocalized", targets: ["AutoLocalized"])
],
targets: [
    .target(name: "AutoLocalized", dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(name: "AutoLocalizedTests", dependencies: ["AutoLocalized"]),
]
)
```

so as I understand adding the ".executable" outputs a file I can then run via Xcode.
I am trying to run a build phase script using that output but I dont know how to access it.

When I try to add dependencies to my target I can find the "autolocalized" executable
[image]

but building the project I get an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found A way, maybe not the best but it workes.
So what I did is adding the package via SPM but without a dependency to any target, that means I had to make sure I build the package manually, finding it in the Build folder and using it directly from there, this was the only way I found to run mac os scripts using build phases in Xcode, I am positive others tried but no one found a good answer, so here it is.